# positioning a div without using absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate something like this.
http://tsawines.com/craft-beer-cider-wine-news/

is there a way for me to achieve it without using absolute.
not really good with css.

I've created fiddle for you to play.
this is what I've done so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/NGj7F/751/

I'm actually looping the div depends on the result of the query.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box" style="height:50px;">
a 
</div>
<div class="box" style="height:30px;">
b
</div>
<div class="box" style="height:80px;">
c
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
border:1px solid green;
width:25%;
float:left;
margin:10px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use masonry plugin - https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @athimohan — They said *without* using absolute positioning.

Comment: @Quentin yes sir. is it possible?